# Using Sql Baseline for Sql Statement

Tags: oracle, baseline

Im creating a Sql Baseline for a particular Sql Statement, I do know Sql Profile works for a particular Sql_Id is it the same way for Sql Baseline

In other words if Sql_id changed for sql statement on every execution will the Sql Baseline help to make oracle use a particular plan

Comment: not sure what you mean by sql_id changing for sql statement on every execution

Answer (score 0):

SQL Profiles can work for other sql_id's provided they have the same force_match_signature and you use "force_match => true" in the accept sql profile command.  SQL Statements will have the same force_match_signature if they differ in say, substitution variables or other minor changes that don't actually change it semantically [roughly speaking].

A SQL Plan Baseline will only work for that same exact SQL_ID, and then, only if the optimizer can generate the plan_hash_value for that SQL given the present operating conditions when the SQL is parsed.

Comment: Thanks  definitely helpful

Comment: @JosiahO You are welcome.  I'd be grateful if you up-voted the answer since you found it helpful ;-) .

Comment: @JosiahO To up vote, click on the little arrow above the number just to the left of the answer. thx. :)